# Looking for title of a film (could be tv show) about god in space

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, religion

I'm not religious but I watched something like this when I was a kid and now I'm just curious and trying to find the title.

The film starts with some astronauts traveling through some kind of blackhole / wormhole / portal-thing, and finding themselves in another universe / dimension where space looks to be red.

At some point they had to fire a laser at an asteroid, then they find out the asteroid is like some kind of cell, and they get attacked by some kind of force that is trying to crush the entire ship.

At the end every one abandons ship except one female character and who stays behind and sees her life flash before her and the ship gets crumbled into a ball.

Sounds like some weird stuff but that's what I thought of a particular movie until I found out it was called "The Langoliers". If anyone knows the answer, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I'm reaching here, but it wouldn't happen to be *Fantasic Voyage* or one of the many other "people shrunken to microscopic size to traverse the human body" films would it? The redness of the location they find themselves in and the asteroid/cell that attacks them could indicate so.

Comment: In what way is this movie about God?

Comment: Aspects of this description mesh with Disney's "The Black Hole", although the matching bits are all out of context.

Comment: The title of your question mentions a "god" in space, but then in your actual question you left out the part about god.

Comment: I'm confused.  What does *The Langoliers* have to do with the rest of your question?

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the episode of the new outer limits entitled "in the blood"

The ship enters a form of hyperspace that they realize is like the bloodstream of an organism and tries to destroy them as a form of immune response.

One female crewmember has flashbacks, and sees a person.

There is **constant** dialog regarding **possible God(s)**, a living creature, and metaphysical arguments about right/wrong in terms of the creature that makes up part of Hyperspace.

Here's a screencap the asteroid/cell in the reddish space:
[image: Asteroid "cells" in space]

Later, one of the crew techs develops a 3D model of "dark stars" that reveals the distant stars form a double helix, implying the objects mimic DNA strands.

Comment: color of the space surrounding them = reddish gold white

Comment: I nabbed a screencap that confirmed @cde's comment and added a little more detail. The quality is poor, but you can [watch the full episode online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXAT5dDzkXo)

Comment: It's a bit long winded and heavy handed dialog, but overall a decent episode.